# dynamic dropdown width along with a background image when the browser window resizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a dynamic dropdown when I change the resolution of the browser window.

[Check](https://jsfiddle.net/51gLv4nz/6/) this fiddle here.

When I resize the window, I want my dropdowns width to increase or shorten.

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
     <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
     </ul> 
      </div>
        </div>
           </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

PS: Also, I have a border around my dropdown which is an image of size 280X35px.

which I am adding as a background-image via CSS.

So I want that image's width to increase at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make the dropdown-part follow the browser width

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/oSHpSWq.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Okay, from reading your comments i think this is the behaviour you want (updated CSS above). The dropdown sizes to the browser width, and the backgorund-image sizes to the dropdowns height and width (scales non proportionally)

Comment: that doesn't make the `background-image` of 100% width.

the dropdown's width becomes 100% but not the image around it

Comment: well, your statement "When I resize the window, I want my dropdowns width to increase or shorten." could be interpreted as this

Comment: apologies. Have put the PS below.

Comment: I have used the deleted code in my project for making dropdown on responsive.Then why do you degrade it?

Comment: @Suraj ive updated the answer with the behaviour i believe you want

Comment: almost there, for some reason, the text I have in my dropdown menu displaces.

Check the screenshot [here](http://prntscr.com/8eb0v2)

Comment: @Suraj ok, its difficult to tell the cause from just the image. Can you replicate it in jsfiddle, or do you have a link to the page in public?

Comment: I don't have it in public and its pretty difficult to have it on fiddle as well. Let me try to put this on fiddle..

Comment: @Suraj try to inspect the element in your browser (press F12, then select the element) and to look at whats causing the margin/padding/positioning and the corresponding CSS

Comment: got it working zedd. I wasn't sure If I can give two values as size for `background-size`

Thanks   :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, adding `background-size: cover;` to your background-image should do the trick.

Comment: It gives issues with Its height. I already tried that.

I have given some height to the dropdown. So when I am giving `background-size: cover;`

It breaks

Comment: you could try repeating the image. You might need to edit the image a little bit :)